# How to use Admob in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, admob, google-play-services

I know that since Google Play Services r30 the lib folder used to add the services to Eclipse is gone. I also know that Eclipse is no longer supported by google and they support Android Studio. But can I still use the latest Google Play Services (Admob) in Eclipse and how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any documentations or tutorials now about Admob in Eclipse. You need to use Android Studio now. Here is a sample [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-how-to-integrate-google-admob-in-your-app/). You can also check this [AdMob with Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/admob-firebase) documentation.

> The best way to use AdMob is with Firebase, but for those publishers who aren't ready to make the switch just yet, Google Mobile Ads will remain available as a standalone SDK. Android publishers can continue to import the `play-services-ads` Gradle artifact without using the Firebase plugin, and iOS developers can use the existing `Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK` CocoaPod. In both cases, the app will get the Google Mobile Ads SDK (including AdMob's ad formats and features) without Firebase.